# Bootstrap "hidden.bs.collapse" doesn't call my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I do have a problem with the trigger-event of bootstrap.
I try to call a function after my content got hidden or shown.

After my search i found this solution, but it doesn't work yet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#widget-box').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       alert("hidden");
   })
   $('#widget-body').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       alert("hidden");
   })
   $('#SearchForm').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       alert("hidden");
   })
});
```

The `widget-box` is the one getting the `collapsed` class.

The `widget-body` is the one getting shown/hidden.

The `SearchForm` is the content of `widget-body` which dis-/appear.

Neither of this 3 functions shows me an alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a first event to start it? Like this [example w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_events&stacked=h)

Answer (score -1):

Use external javascript file. Try to write your jQuery code into external javascript file and link that external javascript file to your html file using script tag.